# JSONP not-supported on rep/rep-graph URL for a reason?

Tags: discussion, reputation, api

I'm currently writing a Chrome extension to monitor stack overflow and give user updates regarding there reputation.

As per this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1830767/so-rep-json-not-working, I suspect that the URL for the rep doesn't support JSONP calls (unlike the flair URL).

Is this for a particular reason? or an overlooked bug/thing.

EDIT: I wasn't sure whether to tag this as a bug or discussion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should wait until the real API is delivered, sometime in the next 3-4 months.

Comment: ok, I can handle that. Thanks for the update.

Comment: Wow, you doubled the 6-8 weeks estimate. Getting more careful? ;)